# New Notification Center

Tags: alert, nsnotificationcenter, banner, ios5

Is there a way to show a notification in the notification center without having push notifications enabled? For example if an email fails to send is there a way i can create a string and display it in the banner at the top?
Sorry i am new to iphone development

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Local Notifications, and this should work as it worked in previous iOS versions I think.
[Push and Local Notifications Appear the Same to Users](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)

As for the underlying logic that goes into creating notifications, I do not believe that the API's are changing that much. What will probably change in my guess, is simply the way that notifications are presented to the end user.

[About Local Notifications and Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1)

Comment: Thanks do you know how to display the banner at the top?

Comment: You're referring to the notification banner I assume? If so, than you do not have to explicitly invoke that. I believe that once you create a local notification, it will automatically handle that for you.

Comment: See this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This shows how to schedule a notification, you can also create one on demand. http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/7/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html